# Javascript Sort Not Working

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort and array of object like this

```
var dataObj = new Array();

function pullData() {
    getData();
    dataObj.sort(function compare(a,b) {
            return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    }
);
```

This runs on startup, and when I check *dataObj* it doesn't have sorted data

However if I call *pullData* or *dataObj.sort(...)* via Chrome Console is see sorted data

I've also tried to assign the variable like this *dataObj = dataObj.sort(...)* but it also doesn't work

Can't figure this out

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to illustrate your problem?

Comment: What does `getData` do, why would it affect `dataObj`? Maybe it is asynchronous?

Comment: getData is reading a local JSON file, but that's a good point, I will check it again